# Azure Application Gateway appGatewayBackendHttpSettings

Tags: azure, azure-application-gateway

I tried to add another appGatewayBackendHttpSettings which pointed to another custom probe but each time I do that i get error 404? Is it possible to add multiple appGatewayBackendHttpSettings in the application gateway when using multi sites?

Answer (score 0):

Yes adding multiple backend http setting with different probes is allowed. Please ensure that all required fields of the setting are entered correctly. You might be hitting a validation error.